# What is the correct way to override the __dir__ method?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.7, introspection

*This question is meant to be more about `__dir__` than about `numpy`.*

I have a subclass of `numpy.recarray` (in python 2.7, numpy 1.6.2), and I noticed `recarray`'s field names are not listed when `dir`ing the object (and therefore ipython's autocomplete doesn't work).

Trying to fix it, I tried overriding `__dir__` in my subclass, like this:

```
def __dir__(self):
    return sorted(set(
               super(MyRecArray, self).__dir__() + \
               self.__dict__.keys() + self.dtype.fields.keys()))
```

which resulted with: `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__dir__'`.
(I found [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue12166) this should actually work in python 3.3...)

As a workaround, I tried:

```
def __dir__(self):
    return sorted(set(
                dir(type(self)) + \
                self.__dict__.keys() + self.dtype.fields.keys()))
```

As far as I can tell, this one works, but of course, not as elegantly.

Questions:

1. Is the latter solution correct in my case, i.e. for a subclass of `recarray`?
2. Is there a way to make it work in the general case?  It seems to me it wouldn't work with multiple inheritance (breaking the `super`-call chain), and of course, for objects with no `__dict__`...
3. Do you know why `recarray` does not support listing its field names to begin with? mere oversight?

Comment: I tried to subclass `recarray` and `dir` **does** show the `recarray` attributes. Can you explain what do you think is missing?

Comment: `self.dtype.fields.keys()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
def __dir__(self):
    return sorted(set(
               dir(super(MyRecArray, self)) + \
               self.__dict__.keys() + self.dtype.fields.keys()))
```

Comment: I must have overlooked this answer.  This is the correct answer.  Accepted now.

Comment: @shx2 this includes attributes unique to the `super` object and doesn't include the object's methods.

Answer (score 6):

Python 2.7+, 3.3+ class mixin that simplifies implementation of *__dir__* method in subclasses. Hope it will help. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/katyukha/c6e5e2b829e247c9b009).

```
import six
class DirMixIn:
    """ Mix-in to make implementing __dir__ method in subclasses simpler
    """

    def __dir__(self):
        if six.PY3:
            return super(DirMixIn, self).__dir__()
        else:
            # code is based on
            # http://www.quora.com/How-dir-is-implemented-Is-there-any-PEP-related-to-that
            def get_attrs(obj):
                import types
                if not hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
                    return []  # slots only
                if not isinstance(obj.__dict__, (dict, types.DictProxyType)):
                    raise TypeError("%s.__dict__ is not a dictionary"
                                    "" % obj.__name__)
                return obj.__dict__.keys()

            def dir2(obj):
                attrs = set()
                if not hasattr(obj, '__bases__'):
                    # obj is an instance
                    if not hasattr(obj, '__class__'):
                        # slots
                        return sorted(get_attrs(obj))
                    klass = obj.__class__
                    attrs.update(get_attrs(klass))
                else:
                    # obj is a class
                    klass = obj

                for cls in klass.__bases__:
                    attrs.update(get_attrs(cls))
                    attrs.update(dir2(cls))
                attrs.update(get_attrs(obj))
                return list(attrs)

            return dir2(self)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. and 3: Yes your solution is correct. `recarray` does not define `__dir__` simply because the default implementation was okay, so they didn't bother implementing it, and `numpy`'s devs did not design the class to be subclassed, so I don't see why they should have bothered.

   It's often a bad idea to subclass built-in types or classes that are not specifically designed for inheritance, thus I'd suggest you to use delegation/composition instead of inheritance, except if there is a particular reason(e.g. you want to pass it to a `numpy` function that excplicitly checks with `isinstance`).
2. No. As you pointed out in python3 they changed the implementation so that there is an `object.__dir__`, but on other python versions I can't see anything that you can do. Also, again, using `recarray` with multiple-inheritance is simply crazy, things *will* break. Multiple-inheritance should be carefully designed, and usually classes are specifically designed to be used with it(e.g. mix-ins). So I wouldn't bother treating this case, since whoever tries it will be bitten by other problems.

   I don't see why you should care for classes that do not have `__dict__`... since your subclass has it how should it break? When you'll change the subclass implementation, e.g. using `__slots__` you could easily change the `__dir__` also. If you want to avoid redefining `__dir__` you can simply define a function that checks for `__dict__` then for `__slots__` etc. Note however that attributes can be generated in subtle ways with `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` and thus you simply **can't** reliably catch all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I accept your point about multiple inheritance.  In my question #2, I'm asking about the best way, in the general case, to implement the following pseudo-code: `return dir_listing(my_super_object) + specific_dir_listing(self)`.  If my superclass overrides `__getattr__`, I rely on it to override `__dir__` correctly.  If my subclass does, I include that part in `specific_dir_listing(self)`.  The question is how to fetch them.