# How to allow custom Class parameter to be tab-completed in ipython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

for example, if I have the following classes

```
class Part(object):
    def __init__(self,part_number,description,rev=None,color=None):
        self.dims = {}
        self.dim_id = 0
        self.rev = rev
        if type(color) is tuple:
            self.color=(color[0]/255.,color[1]/255.,color[2]/255.)
        else:
            self.color = color

     def add_dimension(self,description,value,tol,tol_type = 'sym',dwg_sheet = None, dwg_zone = None,quality = 3):
        self.dims[description] = Dimension(description=description,part=self,value=value,tol=tol,tol_type=tol_type,quality=quality,dwg_sheet=None,dwg_zone=None)


    def __getattr__(self, description):
        return self.dims[description]

class Dimension(object):
    def __init__(self,part,value,tol,tol_type = 'sym', dwg_sheet = None, dwg_zone = None, quality = 3, description = None):
        self.value = value
        self.part=part
        self.tol = tol
        self.tol_type = tol_type
        self.description = description
        self.quality = quality
        self.sigma = self.tol/float(quality)


    def __str__(self):
    return self.description
```

Then I run the following code:

```
a = Part('pn','this is a part')
a.add_dimension('this_is_a_dimension',1.00,0.05)
print a.this_is_a_dimension
```

It returns:

```
this_is_a_dimension
```

the problem is that when I try to do tab completion after typing "`a.`", I get only the following options

```
a.add_dimension
a.color
a.dim_id
a.dims
a.rev
```

I would like to be able to tab-complete to see my new parameter. It would be similar to how column names in Pandas Dataframes work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507848/the-correct-way-to-override-the-dir-method-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can. You must implement a `__dir__()` method for your class, as discussed [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/integrating.html).

This is an example of it working:

```
class bar(object):
    def __init__(self,):
        self.a = 4
        self._morelements=['b']
    def __dir__(self):
        return sorted(set(dir(type(self)) + list(self.__dict__) + self._morelements))

foo=bar()
```

Now if you write `foo.` and press TAB in Ipython you will have as available members both `a` and `b`, although `b` does not exist.

The code for `__dir__()` and a discussion of the limitations of this approach is [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2011_05_21.shtml). In your case, you want to add `description` to the list `self._morelements` inside the function `add_dimension()`.

EDIT: 
And of course you also need to initialize `self._morelements=[]` in the `__init__()`, and add the `__dir__()` function of the example above to your class `Part`

Answer (score 0):

Python is interpreted. So, it only knows about code it has already interpreter. An example of this is: if you try to run the code you posted, you will get an error at the line:

```
self.dims[description] = Dimension(description=description,part=self,value=value,tol=tol,tol_type=tol_type,quality=quality,dwg_sheet=None,dwg_zone=None)
```

the error: **global name 'Dimension' is not defined**. That's because you define the class `Dimension` after. At the time the interpreter reach that line, the class `Dimension` does not exists.

`this_is_a_dimension` attribute of `a` only exists at run time and after the line:

```
a.add_dimension('this_is_a_dimension',1.00,0.05)
```

For accomplish what you want, you'll need some IDE that interprets the python code at edit time.

Comment: I believe iPython must do this, otherwise I'm not sure how pandas achieves this affect.

Comment: @Chris I'm agree. iPython must internally run the python code you are writing. That's why it can autocomplete most of objects attributes.

Comment: SO how would I set it up to show dynamic attributes?