# Making IPython Tab-Complete Hierarchical pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

One of the useful features of IPython is its tab completion, among other things eliminating the need to memorize `pandas.DataFrame` column names.

E.g., suppose we have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bar': [1, 2], 'baz': [3, 4], 'bap': [5, 6]})
```

giving `df` as

```
    bap bar baz
0   5   1   3
1   6   2   4
```

Then we can type

```
df.<Tab>
```

and it will show `bap`, `bar`, and `baz` (among others) as members, as well as attempting to complete them.

Unfortunately, this useful functionality partially disappears with hierarchical dataframes. E.g., if we change things to

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    ('foo', 'bar'): [1, 2], 
    ('foo', 'baz'): [3, 4], 
    ('bap', ''): [5, 6]})
```

giving `df` as

```
    bap foo
        bar baz
0   5   1   3
1   6   2   4
```

then `df.<Tab>` will not autocomplete `bap` or `foo`.

What is the proper way to get this working? I have written a hack which does this (answer below), but am displeased with its reliance on [Python monkey-patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patch). Other answers would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the following monkey-patches seems to remove the symptoms of the problem:

```
_orig_dir = getattr(pd.DataFrame, '__dir__')
def _mutilevel_aware_dir(df):
    multilevels = [tup for tup in df.columns if isinstance(tup, tuple)]
    return _orig_dir(df) + [tup[0] for tup in multilevels]
setattr(pd.DataFrame, '__dir__', _mutilevel_aware_dir)


_orig_get_attr = getattr(pd.DataFrame, '__getattr__')
def _mutilevel_aware_getattr(df, name):
    return _orig_get_attr(df, name)
setattr(pd.DataFrame, '__getattr__', _mutilevel_aware_getattr)
```

IPython apparently indirectly uses the [`__dir__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507848/the-correct-way-to-override-the-dir-method-in-python) method of a `DataFrame` for autocompletion. 
The first function internally scan for tuples, and if they are encountered, returns their first elements as "dummy" members. The second function grabs the `__getattr__` for handling what will be returned when such a dummy member is accessed.

Patching these into the class seems to do the job. However, this is a rather violent solution, and it might have side effects of which I'm unaware.