# How do get dir() to return a non-empty list for a user-defined class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, magic-methods

A variant of this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507848/the-correct-way-to-override-the-dir-method-in-python).
However, it is still not clear to me how to properly deal with `__dir__`
Some have suggested using a class named "[DirMixIn](https://gist.github.com/katyukha/c6e5e2b829e247c9b009)," However, it is poorly documented and it not at all clear how one is supposed to use it.

I wrote a class, and whenever I call its `__dir__` method, I get an empty list. I'm not sure why.

optional [lineno](https://github.com/ActiveState/code/blob/3b27230f418b714bc9a0f897cb8ea189c3515e99/recipes/Python/145297_Grabbing_current_line_number/recipe-145297.py) available [here](https://github.com/ActiveState/code/blob/3b27230f418b714bc9a0f897cb8ea189c3515e99/recipes/Python/145297_Grabbing_current_line_number/recipe-145297.py)

```
# from lineno import lineno
try:
    lineno
except NameError:
     lineno = lambda: ''

class ForceGetattr:

    def __init__(self, inner_self):

        print(lineno(), '  |  ', 'dir(self) == ', dir(self)) # debug

        while isinstance(inner_self, type(self)):
            inner_self = object.__getattribute__(inner_self, '_inner_self')

        object.__setattr__(self, '_inner_self', inner_self) # self.inner_self = inner_self
        create_attrs_from_inner = object.__getattribute__(self, 'create_attrs_from_inner')
        create_attrs_from_inner()

        print(lineno(), '  |  ', 'dir(self) == ', dir(self))

    def create_attrs_from_inner(self):

        get_inner_attrs = object.__getattribute__(self, 'get_inner_attrs') # debug

        print(lineno(), '  |  ', 'dir(self) == ', dir(self))

        inner_attrs = get_inner_attrs()
        assert(len(inner_attrs) > 0)

        ignore = object.__getattribute__(self, 'ignore')
        already_have = object.__getattribute__(self, 'already_have')

        print(lineno(), '  |  ', 'dir(self) == ', dir(self)) # debug

        for attr_name in (ignore | already_have):
                inner_attrs.discard(attr_name)

        assert(len(inner_attrs) > 0)

        print(lineno(), '  |  ', 'dir(self) == ', dir(self)) # debug

        for attr_name in inner_attrs:
            make_proxy = object.__getattribute__(self, 'make_proxy')
            attr = make_proxy(attr_name)
            setattr(self, attr_name, attr)

        print(lineno(), '  |  ', 'dir(self) == ', dir(self)) # debug

        return

    def get_inner_attrs(self):
        inner_self = object.__getattribute__(self, '_inner_self')
        dr = set(dir(inner_self))
        dt = type(inner_self).__dict__.keys()
        if hasattr(inner_self, '__dict__'):
            dt = set(inner_self.__dict__.keys())
#        print('dr == \n', dr)
#        print('\n\n')
#        print(dt)
#        print('dr == \n', dr)
        uni = dr | dt
        return uni

    ignore = frozenset({'__class__', '__mro__', '__new__', '__init__', '__setattr__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__'})

    def make_proxy(self, attr_name):
        inner_self = object.__getattribute__(self, '_inner_self')
        def proxy():
            return getattr(inner_self, attr_name)
        return proxy

    def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
        inner_self = object.__getattribute__(self, '_inner_self')
        attr = inner_self.attr_name
        return attr

#    def __dir__(self):
#        return

    already_have = frozenset({})
    # already_have = frozenset({'__iter__', '__getitem__'})

#    def __iter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
#        f = getattr(self, '__iter__')
#        return f(*args, **kwargs)
#
#    def __getitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
#        f = getattr(self, '__getitem__')
#        return f(*args, **kwargs)
#
#    def __setitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
#        f = getattr(self, '__setitem__')
#        return f(*args, **kwargs)
#
#    def __add__(self, *args, **kwargs):
#        f = getattr(self, '__add__')
#        return f(*args, **kwargs)
#
#    def __sub__(self, *args, **kwargs):
#        f = getattr(self, '__sub__')
#        return f(*args, **kwargs)
#
#    def __mul__(self, *args, **kwargs):
#        f = getattr(self, '__mul__')
#        return f(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This class has no `__dir__()` method defined...

Comment: If `inner_self` has a `__dir__()` method, then `ForceGetattr` should too. This is because `ForceGetattr` calls `setattr(self, attr_name, attr)` for every attribute `attr` in inner_self.