# Calling builtin dir from overrided dir method in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to override the **dir** method in a Python class. Inside I want to call the builtin dir method, but my attempts at calling it seem to be calling my method, rather than the default implementation.

[The correct way to override the __dir__ method in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507848/the-correct-way-to-override-the-dir-method-in-python)
This question seemed relevant but doesn't answer the question since it seems their issue was with extending a numpy class, not with calling the default dir implementation for the class

Relevant code

```
def __dir__(self):
    return builtins.dir(self) + self.fields()
```

In other words I want everything that would normally be listed plus some other things, but the builtins.dir() call just calls this function recursively.

I'm testing this in Python 3.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since overriding `__dir__` only matters in class' instances, you can do this:

```
class Test:
    def test(self):
        print('hey')

    def __dir__(self):
        return dir(Test) + ['hello']
```

Notice that `dir(Test)` is different from `dir(Test())` because only the latter calls `Test.__dir__`.

Using `dir(super())` inside `Test.__dir__` also kinda works, but it only provides you with data for the *parent* class, so that `dir(Test())` won't contain the names of the attributes present exclusively in the class `Test`.

Comment: This works ok although I modified it to be dir(type(self)) since I'm working with a subclass of the class. Also, I think it would be good to add the dictionary as well, since now you are skipping the instance attributes. So you have `dir(type(self)) + list(self.__dict__.keys()) + self.fields()` The linked SO question in my question also references super, which as you mention I found not to work as expected.

Comment: I should also mention that although this works fine for me as a workaround it doesn't answer the question of how one might call a builtin function directly. I'm surprised that builtins.dir() calls my method.

Comment: @Jimbo, you _are_ calling the builtin function `dir` directly with `builtins.dir`. Overriding the `dir` function itself and overriding a `__dir__` method are very different.

Comment: I am confused. Calling `builtins.dir` from my `__dir__` method results in recursion (and hitting a recursion limit). It is not clear to me how you would, from within the user defined `__dir__` method, call a function that returns the same thing as if the `__dir__` method did not exist.