# Getting a concise version of dir()

Tags: python

I want to find a generic way to list a python object attributes (names and values) but in a concise way.
This works pretty well when using `vars()`, but you can't use it if there's no `__dict__`; and `dir()` is full of uninteresting attributes.

I know that's kind of random, but PyCharm is doing something similar somehow, here's an example for the `numpy ndarray` object, which has no `__dict__`; and `dir()` contains 161 attributes. I tried to remove private and callable values from `dir()`, but still, there are dozens.

[image]

Any idea for how PyCharm is doing it? Is there a chance they have a special treatment for `numpy` objects for example?

Comment: The set of "uninteresting" attributes is large, but predictable. It wouldn't surprise me if they are just being filtered explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, do you have a source or an idea where or how can I find these predictable values list? @chepner

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507848/what-is-the-correct-way-to-override-the-dir-method

Comment: I don't think it's published, but you can construct a useful list just by looking at `dir(x)` for lots of values of `x` with different types. (Most of which, though, are CPython implementation details. It would be interesting to see what happens if you could set PyCharm to use something like `pypy`, to see if anything changes.)

Comment: That's funny I just figured out that the value that PyCharm presents (of this ndarray instance), is the value of the "real" attribute. Maybe it does hard-coded after all. @chepner

Comment: I'll bet that PyCharm has dedicated code for displaying numpy arrays, pandas series, etc. because these are popular library, rather than using a generic object decoder.

Answer (score 1):

For classes defined in Python, you can use `__dict__` (if any) on the object plus **`__slots__`** on its type (if any).  For **built-in** types in CPython, you might also want to search the class’s dictionary for objects of type `types.GetSetDescriptorType`, `types.MemberDescriptorType`, and/or `types.DynamicClassAttribute`.  This misses most things that have `__names__`, though it can still be useful to filter the ones that remain.

Comment: It is better now, but still many other items. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @GalShahar: What “other items”?  I’m not sure it’s possible to do better than the above without type-specific rules, but if you give an example we could find out.